# Xamarin forms Navigation not releasing Memory

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms using Xamarin.forms(version 2.0.0) and I get stuck in an Issue where my Application is getting Crash again and again due to memory leak. I suspect that is because When navigating a page off of a navigation stack, the memory for the view is not released.
Even I user Dispose() Method to release the unused references. But still having this bug. Heap space is growing every time I revisit.
Below are the sample code how I'm performing navigation stack (push/pop).

```
    Navigation.PushModalAsync (new NewPage ());
    Navigation.PopAsync ());
```

Is there any solution for this issue or there is still bug in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: I have the same issue than you, did you follow any approach?

Answer (score 3):

PopAsync is not paired for PushModalAsync

You should use PushModalAsync() pair with PopModalAsync().

And PushAsync() pair with PopAsync().

Then you will not found memory leak.

Comment: I use PushModalAsync() when I navigate and PopModalAsync() when I go back but I have the same issue...